# Declaring User-Defined variables in the C shell in UNIX read-only

Tags: csh, readonly

I'm having trouble finding documentation, but what is the command to make a user defined variable in the c shell read-only in unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set -r`:

```
% set -r trousers = "on fire"
% echo $trousers
on fire

% set trousers = waterrrrr
set: $trousers is read-only.

% echo $trousers
on fire
```

This is documented in the `tcsh` manpage, `tcsh(1)`, and should work for both `csh` & `tcsh` (but I think all `csh`'s floating around are `tcsh` these days).

[Here is the online version of the manpage](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Builtin_commands.html); I can't link directly to the applicable section, search for '*set -r*'.